# Mutate and if else function to create new column

Tags: r, if-statement, mutate

It may be a very easy question, but so far I failed.

My dataset looks like this

| Duration | Unit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | day |
| 3 | month |
| 5 | weeks |

What I want to do is to create a new column for the number of days depending on the unit. So 3 months should be 90 days, 5 weeks should be 35 days. And in case of unit is day, the value of day should be placed in my new column without any calculation.

So the result should look like this

| Duration | Unit | Duration_calculated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | day | 1 |
| 3 | month | 90 |
| 5 | weeks | 35 |

Here is the exmaple dataset

```
Duration <- c(1,3,5)    
Unit <- c("day", "month", "weeks")     
dataset <- data.frame(Duration, Unit)
```

I've tried a combination of mutate and if else function, but it worked not out for me.

Comment: Average month length is 30.437. Why is it `day`,  `month`, but `weeks` - plural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `case_when()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Duration_calculated = case_when(
    Unit == "day" ~ Duration,
    Unit == "month" ~ Duration * 30,
    Unit == "weeks" ~ Duration * 7
  ))

  Duration  Unit Duration_calculated
1        1   day                   1
2        3 month                  90
3        5 weeks                  35
```

Or if you stick on `ifelse` or `if_else` we could use nested `if_else()` statement:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Duration_calculated = if_else(
  Unit == "day", Duration,
  if_else(Unit == "month", Duration * 30,
          if_else(Unit == "weeks", Duration * 7, NA_real_)
  )
))
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a lookup vector, then match:

```
dataset <- data.frame(Duration = c(1, 3, 5),
                      Unit = c("day", "month", "week"))

lookup <- setNames(c(1, 7, 30.437), c("day", "week", "month"))

dataset$Duration_calculated <- dataset$Duration * lookup[ dataset$Unit ]

dataset
#   Duration  Unit Duration_calculated
# 1        1   day               1.000
# 2        3 month              91.311
# 3        5  week              35.000
```